# I18n.locale getting reset to :en in between controller and the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, locale, spree, rails-i18n

I'm trying to internationalize a Rails/Spree app using spree's own `spree_i18n` gem, but I can't get it to work.

[I made a minimal app which recreates the problem here.](https://github.com/georgemillo/spree_i18n_fail)

To cut a long story short, I have the following code in my ApplicationController:

```
before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  puts I18n.locale
end
```

And code in my view which should be translated (`<%= t("whatever") %>`). But no matter what I do, the text is always output in English.

With some additional code for debugging, I can see that once `set_locale` is called but while execution is still within the controller, the locale is correct (e.g. if I visit the url `/?locale=es`, then the `puts` statement in the above controller code outputs `es`).

But by the time execution has reached the view, the locale has somehow been reset to `en`. (E.g. adding `<% raise I18n.locale.to_s %>` within the view raises "en" as an error message.)

I've [opened an issue on Spree's Github](https://github.com/spree/spree_i18n/issues/460) because as far as I can tell I've followed their instructions exactly and it's still not working, but I may still be missing something. Why isn't the locale getting set properly?

(Note: I should add that the `Spree.t` doesn't work either, not just `t`.)

EDIT: If you look at the comment on my Github issue, you'll see that I got it working. However, I'm 99% sure that my solution is a hack and there's a better method I should be using. Bounty goes to whoever can tell me what I'm dong wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spree I18n gives a way to set default language: on `config/application.rb` with
`config.i18n.default_locale = :es`

And the possibility of setting the languages to be changed. Perhaps on `config/initializers/spree_i18n.rb`

```
SpreeI18n::Config.available_locales = [:en, :es, :de] 
SpreeI18n::Config.supported_locales = [:en, :es, :de]
```

After that, you can remove `set_locale` on ApplicationController, because it has no effect.

With this at place, it works like a charm.

Edited:

I change the message of error because I want to be sure that it works:

```
<%= product_description(@product) rescue Spree.t(:product_has_no_description) +
' ' + Spree.t(:action) %>
```

And I add a new product without description. Running the server at localhost

In english I see: "This product has no description Action"

In spanish I see: "Este producto no tiene descripción Acción"

In deutsch I see: "Produkt hat keine Beschreibung Aktion"

Exactly the expected.

You can see the source with changes at [github](https://github.com/alejandrobabio/spree_i18n_fail)

Answer (score 3):

It is unclear to me how `Spree` handles localization and in your `routes.rb` you only mounts engine.

Basically you should start localize your app within `routes.rb` by adding:

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
  # routing and engines go here
end
```

Now, you need to keep your `params[:locale]` across requests, so add to app controller:

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  logger.debug "default_url_options is passed options: #{options.inspect}\n"
  { locale: I18n.locale }
end
```

Last, detect and set locale for current request, depending on your input data:

```
before_filter :set_locale

def set_locale
  if defined?(params) && params[:locale]
    I18n.locale = params[:locale]
  elsif current_user && current_user.language_id.present?
    I18n.locale = current_user.language.code
  elsif defined?(request)
    I18n.locale = extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
  end
  I18n.locale ||= I18n.default_locale
  I18n.locale = :en unless valid_languages.include?(I18n.locale.to_sym)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be `using/setting` the following in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`, which doesn't work:

```
before_action :set_locale
def set_locale
    I18n.locale =
    Spree::Frontend::Config[:locale] =
    Spree::Backend::Config[:locale] = :LOCALE
end
```

In `core/lib/spree/core/controller_helpers/common.rb` there is another `before_filter` called `set_user_language`. That filter gets called and re-sets the locale to the value of `session[:locale]`, or if that's not defined it uses default locale.

To solve the issue, set `session[:locale]` = :LOCALE in your before_filter.